# Frequency by class

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to plot by class the frequency of the usernames. My data are

```
    Class   Username
0   0.0     user1
1   0.0     user2
2   1.0     user3
3   1.0     user3
4   0.0     user4
... ... ...
32  0.0     user34
33  0.0     user1
34  1.0     user32
35  1.0     user32
36  0.0     user3
```

I did the following:

`df.groupby(["Username"]).count().reset_index().sort_values(by=['Class'], ascending=False)`
, but it gives me Class as Frequency (and I would prefer to not call the frequency Class) and not grouped based o the Class.
My expected output should be

```
    Freq    Username   Class 
    2       user1       0
    1       user2       0
    2       user4       0 
    1       user3       0
    ... ...
    1       user34      1
    2       user32      1
    2       user3       1
```

How should I get the results above (or something similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` both the Username and Class and get the size of each group.  A few extra commands to format the output.  Using your data outside of the `...`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Class','Username']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Freq'})
   Class Username  Freq
0    0.0    user1     2
1    0.0    user2     1
2    0.0    user3     1
3    0.0   user34     1
4    0.0    user4     1
5    1.0    user3     2
6    1.0   user32     2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tom. In case I wanted to order per each class the usernames more frequent, should I add at the end `.sort_values(by=['Freq'], ascending=False)` only?

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
df.value_counts(['Class','Username'])
```

Comment: I got this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: @The_Ark Probably b/c you need `pandas` 1.1.0 or greater, [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html).  You can check with `print(pd.__version__)`